# List with multiple values per key

Tags: c#, .net, list

how do we create a list with multiple values for example , list[0] contains three values {"12","String","someValue"} the Some value is associated to the two other values i want to use a list rather than using an array

```
string[, ,] read = new string[3, 3, 3];
```

Comment: struct Arr { List < String > values; };
Arr[] ar = new Arr[n];

In other words just wrap it into other struct.

Comment: What abt Dictionary<string,List<string>>?

Comment: Why not make an actual class that describes what those values mean?

Comment: Also, a `string[,,]` is a three-dimensional array.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Why not have a `List` of `Tuple`'s? It *can* be unclear, but it will do what you are after:

```
var list = new List<Tuple<string, string, string>>();
list.Add(new Tuple<string, string, string>("12", "something", "something"));
```

Although it would probably be better to give these values semantic meaning. Perhaps if you let us know what the values are *intending* to show, then we can give some ideas on how to make it much more readable.

Answer (score 6):

Use list of lists:

```
List<List<string>> read;
```

Or if you want key-multiple values relation, use dictionary of lists:

```
Dictionary<string, List<string>> read;
```

Answer (score 3):

You could use `Tuple`:

```
List<Tuple<String, String, String>> listOfTuples = new List<Tuple<String, String, String>>();
listOfTuples.Add(new Tuple<String, String, String>("12", "String", "someValue"));
```

The MSDN:

> http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd383822.aspx

Answer (score 3):

How about using a [`Lookup<TKey,TElement>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb460184.aspx)?

From MSDN:

> A Lookup resembles a Dictionary. The
>   difference is that a Dictionary maps keys to single
>   values, whereas a Lookup maps keys to collections of
>   values.

Answer (score 0):

Or you can make a separate class that will contain all the values. Let's call this class Entity:

`class Entity{int i; String s; Object SomeValue;}`
  and then just do

`List<Entity> list=new List<Entity>()`

Alternatively you can use a matrix.