# Simple way to access data of different types within a nested array?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am making a competitive racing game where the primary method of transportation is a magic umbrella where players float around racing to predetermined destinations like Mary Poppins.

I need a way to store the types of Umbrellas available for use. For instance, if they choose to change from a full size "automatic" umbrella, to a faster lightweight solution like a "pocket" umbrella, I can use the array below as such:

```
    Dictionary<string, Dictionary<string, double>> Umbrellas = new Dictionary<string, Dictionary<string, double>>
         {
             { "automatic", new Dictionary<string, double> { { "canopy_scale", 0.80 }, { "rib_count", 24 }, { "pole_height", 16 } } },
             { "pocket", new Dictionary<string, double> { { "canopy_scale", 0.23 }, { "rib_count", 12 }, { "pole_height", 7 } } },
             { "golf", new Dictionary<string, double> { { "canopy_scale", 0.70 }, { "rib_count", 30 }, { "pole_height", 20 } } }
         };

     var ChangeCanopy = true;
     var UmbrellaType = 2;
     var ChangeRibs = true;
     var UmbrellaRibs = 1;

     if(ChangeCanopy){


         var UmbrellaType = "";

         if( ChangeCanopy == 1 ){

             //To scale the objects canopy to "automatic" size:
             UmbrellaType = "automatic";

         }else if( ChangeCanopy == 2 ){

             //To scale the objects canopy to "pocket" size:
             umbrellaProperty = "canopy_scale";

         }else if( ChangeCanopy == 3 ){

             //To scale the objects canopy to "golf" size:
             umbrellaProperty = "canopy_scale";

         }else{
             //Default if | input != (1,2,3)
             umbrellaProperty = "automatic";
         }

         var scale = Umbrellas[UmbrellaType][umbrellaProperty];

         Umbrella.transform.localScale = new Vector3[scale, scale, scale];


     }else if(ChangeRibs){


         var RibType = "";

         if( UmbrellaRibs == 1 ){

     ... ect.
```

This is not how the array would be used in practice, its an over exageration of its functionality. The primary purpose of doing it this way is to rely only on the data structure itself without any function overhead, or complex classes. Can this be done in a more manageable way then this horrid nested array declaration?

In addition, can an array be nested inside an array, with different types of data where it can contain strings with float or ints as well? like this:

```
     Dictionary Umbrellas = new Dictionary<string>;

     Umbrellas["automatic"]= { "canopy_scale", 0.80 }, { "rib_count", 24 }, { "pole_height", 16 };
     Umbrellas["pocket"]= { "canopy_scale", 0.23 }, { "rib_count", 12 }, { "pole_height", 7 };
     Umbrellas["golf"]= { "canopy_scale", 0.70 }, { "rib_count", 30 }, { "pole_height", 20 } };

     Umbrellas["color"]= { "string", new Dictionary<string> }, { "hex", new Dictionary<string> } };
     Umbrellas["color"]["string"]={ "automatic", "red" }, { "pocket", "green" }, { "golf", "blue" };
     Umbrellas["color"]["hex"]={ "automatic", 0xFF0000 }, { "pocket", 0x00FF00 }, { "golf", 0x0000FF };
```

Is there any way to achieve this, or even better, a simple way to organize data that can potentially achieve better performance? I have searched and cannot find how to nest arrays and access the value of differing data types by key-name.

Comment: You should create an Umbrella class, which has properties for all those things. Then you only need a `List<Umbrella>`, and you can query for automatic umbrellas like: `var autoUmbrellas = umbrellas.Where(u => u.UmbrellaType == UmbrellaType.Automatic)`. What you are trying to do is why classes were invented in the first place: encapsulate related data into a single object, with properties, methods and events that allow manipulation of data and subscription to state changes.

Comment: That's exactly what I am trying to do, though without classes. ;) All the data in the array would describe properties of the objects, but with ints, floats, strings. I would prefer to access them with a nested key hierarchy. Could Tuple's be nested like in this answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/17341478/8005218) I am using "unity C#", some C# stuff doesn't work in unity ...